# Multiple select box is not working in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html-select

I am using the following code to select multiple values.

```
 <select name="video" multiple="multiple" id="form-field-select-2" class="form-control">
 <%video.each do |option|%>
 <option><%=option%> </option>
 <%end%>
 </select>
```

But after submitting form its not giving all selected values,instead of its giving only the last selected value.

Please share if you have any idea about this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 <select name="video[]" multiple="multiple" id="form-field-select-2" class="form-control">
 <%video.each do |option|%>
 <option><%=option%> </option>
 <%end%>
 </select>
```

You need to make sure that you are sending an array of answers by changing the name to `video[]`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `select_tag` too

```
<%= select_tag 'video', options_from_collection_for_select(Video.all,"id","name"),  :multiple => true, class: 'form-control'%>
```

For more details,see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)**