# Select2 getting multiple selections after form POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I have this select2 multi-selection dropdown that works fine on the client side but only posts the last selection users make:

```
<select class="searchable-dropdown form-control form-control-md" name="payment_methods" id="payment-methods-send" multiple="multiple">
 <%= options_for_select( (::Transaction::SEND_METHODS).collect{ |m| [t(m[:name]), m[:name].parameterize ]}, selected: params[:payment_method] ) %>
</select>
```

It generates the following markup:

```
<select class="searchable-dropdown form-control form-control-md" name="payment_methods" id="payment-methods-receive" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="coupons">Coupons</option>
 <option value="paypal">Paypal</option>
 <option value="skrill">Skrill</option>
 <option value="revolut">Revolut</option>
 <option value="zelle">Zelle</option>
 <option value="transferwise">Transferwise</option>
 <option value="swift-bank-transfer">SWIFT bank transfer</option>
 <option value="european-bank-transfer">European bank transfer</option>
 <option value="us-bank-transfer">US bank transfer</option>
 <option value="uk-bank-transfer">UK bank transfer</option>
 <option value="check">Check</option>
</select>
```

I've used this to initialize the control:

```
$( ".searchable-dropdown" ).select2({ theme: "bootstrap" });
```

After making several selections and sending the form, I am getting this within params:

```
"payment_methods":"paypal"
```

Paypal was indeed selected (last) but so were a bunch of other selections.

Was it not supposed to send them comma-separated or something? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, looks like I wasn't asking Google the right question...

[Multiple select box is not working in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646076/multiple-select-box-is-not-working-in-rails)

> You need to make sure that you are sending an array of answers by
>   changing the name to payment_methods[]